# Print exact variable values with percentage symbols on pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

[image]

I would like to represent on a pie chart, the exact same values of the column "Percentage Answers" with a percentage symbol (100 % instead of 100.0). I researched similar questions in Stackoverflow, and they seemed to use `autopct`. I don't seem to use it properly (I don't understand it neither) to display the same values of my column, with %.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is a small reproducible code :

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
 
# initialize list of lists
data = [['Basics 1', 100.0], ['Basics 2', 100.0], ['Basics 3', 40.0]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Course', 'Percentage Answers'])

# Plot teachers feedback percentages
my_labels= list(df['Course'])
plt.pie(df["Percentage Answers"], labels = my_labels, autopct='%0.0f%%')
plt.title("Percentage of Teacher's Feedback Participation")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: please provide a fully reproducible code (i.e. a code with data that one can copy paste and run to generate the current graph)

Comment: The percentages of `autopct` are the fraction of the pie, where the full pie represents 100%: If you want to show something else, you could make it part of the labels.  Could you please add reproducible data (in text form) and the code you tried to change the lables (also in text)?

Comment: @JohanC I just added a small code in my description. Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this, i will show you my own example , but you can simply apply to your example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy


# Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs', 'Tgs', 'Lgs'
sizes = [65, 30, 45, 10, 34, 44]

dic = dict()
for i in sizes:
    dic[numpy.round(i / sum(sizes) * 100,2)] = str(int(i)) + " %"

def raw_value(val):
    return dic[numpy.round(val,2)]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes,labels=labels, autopct=raw_value)
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.

plt.show()
```